# How to implement quicksort method for a pair of generics?

Tags: java, quicksort, bluej

So I have a class pair which stores two variables: key and value. I also have a MyArrayList class that extends ArrayList and includes a quicksort method that will sort an inserted arraylist of integers. My question would be how to make this quicksort method work with pairs instead of a single values in an arraylist.
Pair class:

```
class Pair<K extends Comparable<K>, V extends Comparable<V>> {
public K key;
public V value;

// Default Constructor
public Pair(){
}

// Parametrized Constructor
public Pair(K key, V value){
this.key = key;
this.value = value;
}

@Override
public String toString() {
return "Pair {" + this.key + ", " + this.value + "}";
}

// Setter Functions:
public void setKey(K key){
this.key = key;
}

public void setValue(V value){
this.value = value;
}

// Getter Functions:
public K getKey(){
return key;
}

public V getValue(){
return value;
}

}
```

MyArrayList class:

```
public class MyArrayList<K extends Comparable<K>, V extends Comparable<V>> extends ArrayList<Pair<K,V>>{
     MyArrayList<Integer ,Integer> array = new MyArrayList<Integer,Integer>();

     public static void main(String[] args){
     MyArrayList<String,Integer> array = new MyArrayList<String,Integer>();
    
    }   
 
  public String String(){
      ArrayList<String> copy = (ArrayList<String>)array.clone();
      return copy.toString();
    }
    
  public ArrayList QuickSort(ArrayList<Integer> arr){
      
      if (arr.size()< 1) return arr;
      
    ArrayList<Integer> sorted = new ArrayList<Integer>();
    ArrayList<Integer> lesser = new ArrayList<Integer>();
    ArrayList<Integer> greater = new ArrayList<Integer>();
    
    Integer pivot = arr.get(arr.size()-1); 
    
    for (int i = 0; i < array.size()-1; i++)
    {
        if (arr.get(i) < pivot)
            lesser.add(arr.get(i));    
        else
            greater.add(arr.get(i));   
    }

    lesser = QuickSort(lesser);
    greater = QuickSort(greater);

    lesser.add(pivot);
    lesser.addAll(greater);
    sorted = lesser;

    return sorted;
      
    }
    
    
    
}
```

Comment: Why do you want to implement the sorting yourself?
Your list-items already implement Comparable, so you can just call .sort() on your list.

Answer (score 0):

Well, you just kinda have to do it ;). You first have to decide what it means to compare two of your `Pair`s.  I chose to compare their keys.  It would be an easy change to compare their values instead, or any other kind of comparison you wanted to devise.  Once decided, you just have to override `compareTo` in your `Pair` class to implement that decision.

You have to change your sort code to work with your `Pair<K, V>` instead of with `Integer`s.  The most substantive change really is to use the `compareTo` method instead of a standard operator.  I did the conversion, just for fun, doing some other cleanup as I went along:

```
import java.util.ArrayList;

class Pair<K extends Comparable<K>, V extends Comparable<V>> {
    public K key;
    public V value;

    // Parametrized Constructor
    public Pair(K key, V value) {
        this.key = key;
        this.value = value;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "Pair {" + this.key + ", " + this.value + "}";
    }

    // Setter Functions:
    public void setKey(K key) {
        this.key = key;
    }

    public void setValue(V value) {
        this.value = value;
    }

    // Getter Functions:
    public K getKey() {
        return key;
    }

    public V getValue() {
        return value;
    }

    public int compareTo(Pair<K, V> o) {
        return key.compareTo(o.getKey());
    }
}

class MyArrayList<K extends Comparable<K>, V extends Comparable<V>> extends ArrayList<Pair<K, V>> {

    private ArrayList<Pair<K, V>> quicksort(ArrayList<Pair<K, V>> arr) {

        if (arr.size() < 2) return arr;

        ArrayList<Pair<K, V>> lesser = new ArrayList<>();
        ArrayList<Pair<K, V>> greater = new ArrayList<>();

        Pair<K, V> pivot = arr.get(arr.size() - 1);

        for (int i = 0; i < arr.size() - 1; i++) {
            if (arr.get(i).compareTo(pivot) < 0)
                lesser.add(arr.get(i));
            else
                greater.add(arr.get(i));
        }

        lesser = quicksort(lesser);
        greater = quicksort(greater);

        lesser.add(pivot);
        lesser.addAll(greater);

        return lesser;
    }

    public String toString() {
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        sb.append('[');
        for (Pair<K, V> p : this) {
            if (sb.length() > 1)
                sb.append(',');
            sb.append('{').append(p.key).append(':').append(p.value).append('}');
        }
        sb.append(']');
        return sb.toString();
    }


    public void quicksort() {
        ArrayList<Pair<K, V>> r = quicksort(this);
        for (int i = 0 ; i < r.size() ; i++)
            set(i, r.get(i));
    }
}

public class Test {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        MyArrayList<Integer, String> pairs = new MyArrayList<>();
        pairs.add(new Pair<>(7, "foo"));
        pairs.add(new Pair<>(23, "blah"));
        pairs.add(new Pair<>(24, "xxx"));
        pairs.add(new Pair<>(14, "blech"));
        pairs.add(new Pair<>(3, "abc"));
        pairs.add(new Pair<>(-24, "wow"));

        System.out.println(pairs);
        pairs.quicksort();
        System.out.println(pairs);
    }
}
```

Result:

```
[{7:foo},{23:blah},{24:xxx},{14:blech},{3:abc},{-24:wow}]
[{-24:wow},{3:abc},{7:foo},{14:blech},{23:blah},{24:xxx}]
```

Comment: So how do you know its only comparing either key or value in the arraylist? Wouldn't the i in the for loop go through both of those variables? Also thank you